# Getting CUPS and printing working on Ubuntu with Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: ubuntu, printing, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm building a cross platform printing app and need to test it on various Linux. I could use VMs but I've got WSL just sitting here working and it will be a lot more convenient, at least initially just to use it.

I have installed CUPS but it won't run:

```
$ dpkg -s cups
Package: cups
Status: install ok installed
...
$ sudo systemctl restart cups.service
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
```

I found a single guide on the 'net for printing in WSL and it make it sound like it "just works": https://www.scivision.dev/scanningprinting-with-windows-subsystem-for-linux/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sudo service cups start`
or 
`sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/cups start`

`systemctl` is dependent on systemd as your error message says